# How to plot function of an array or alternative?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.plot(time,phi(time))
```

isnt working... whyyyyy????

tried to apply the function individually

```
import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81 l = 2 mu = 0.1

PHI_0 = np.pi / 3 PHI_PUNKT_0 = 0

def berrechne_phi_zwei_punkt(phi, phi_punkt):
   return -mu * phi_punkt - (g/l) * np.sin(phi)

def phi(t):
   phi = PHI_0
   phi_punkt = PHI_PUNKT_0
   delta_t = 0.001
   for time in np.arange(0,t,delta_t):
    phi_zwei_punkt = berrechne_phi_zwei_punkt(
      phi, phi_punkt
    )
    phi += phi_punkt * delta_t
    phi_punkt += phi_zwei_punkt * delta_t
   return phi

delta_t2 = 0.1
t_max = 10
time = np.arange(0, t_max+delta_t2 , delta_t2)
print(time)

plt.plot(time,phi(time))

plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

I want the correct plot of the function but it outputs "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe reformat your code so that it is easier to distinguish which commands are intended to be within the scope of the loop and which not

Comment: @hpaulj plt.plot(time,phi(time)) doesnt work. I want to evaluate the defined function phi(t) for all values of the array.

Comment: Can you narrow that down?  Is it the `plot` command itself that's raising the error?  Or may be it's the `phi(time)` step?

Comment: @hpaulj yep its the phi(time)... does it work for u?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to calculate `phi(time)`, I think you want to calculate `phi(t)` where `t` is each element of `time`.

The important section is here:

```
def phi(t):
    # ...
    for time in np.arange(0,t,delta_t):
```

[`np.arange()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) takes a number as its second argument, so your `phi()` function must take a number. However, you call it with an array:

```
time = np.arange(0, t_max+delta_t2 , delta_t2)
print(time)

plt.plot(time,phi(time))
```

You can either loop through `time` calling `phi(t)` on each item, or vectorize your `phi()` function to take an array. The second option will probably be faster to run, but it's not always easy to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some guidance on how to debug and how to provide an informative question.

Here's your code, with a few syntax corrections.

```
In [3]: g = 9.81; l = 2; mu = 0.1 
   ...:  
   ...: PHI_0 = np.pi / 3; PHI_PUNKT_0 = 0 
   ...:  
   ...: def berrechne_phi_zwei_punkt(phi, phi_punkt): 
   ...:    return -mu * phi_punkt - (g/l) * np.sin(phi) 
   ...:  
   ...: def phi(t): 
   ...:    phi = PHI_0 
   ...:    phi_punkt = PHI_PUNKT_0 
   ...:    delta_t = 0.001 
   ...:    for time in np.arange(0,t,delta_t): 
   ...:     phi_zwei_punkt = berrechne_phi_zwei_punkt( 
   ...:       phi, phi_punkt 
   ...:     ) 
   ...:     phi += phi_punkt * delta_t 
   ...:     phi_punkt += phi_zwei_punkt * delta_t 
   ...:    return phi 
   ...:  
   ...: delta_t2 = 0.1 
   ...: t_max = 10 
   ...: time = np.arange(0, t_max+delta_t2 , delta_t2)                          
In [4]: time                                                                    
Out[4]: 
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
        1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,
        2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2,
        3.3,  3.4,  3.5,  3.6,  3.7,  3.8,  3.9,  4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,
        4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9,  5. ,  5.1,  5.2,  5.3,  5.4,
        5.5,  5.6,  5.7,  5.8,  5.9,  6. ,  6.1,  6.2,  6.3,  6.4,  6.5,
        6.6,  6.7,  6.8,  6.9,  7. ,  7.1,  7.2,  7.3,  7.4,  7.5,  7.6,
        7.7,  7.8,  7.9,  8. ,  8.1,  8.2,  8.3,  8.4,  8.5,  8.6,  8.7,
        8.8,  8.9,  9. ,  9.1,  9.2,  9.3,  9.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.7,  9.8,
        9.9, 10. ])
```

`phi` with a single works fine:

```
In [5]: phi(1)                                                                  
Out[5]: -0.46063859245390176
```

But with the array, `time`, it produces your error:

```
In [6]: phi(time)                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cdd824beb99b> in <module>
----> 1 phi(time)

<ipython-input-3-bc74d5ec1a6c> in phi(t)
     10    phi_punkt = PHI_PUNKT_0
     11    delta_t = 0.001
---> 12    for time in np.arange(0,t,delta_t):
     13     phi_zwei_punkt = berrechne_phi_zwei_punkt(
     14       phi, phi_punkt

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You should have given us that **full** traceback/error message.  It helps casual readers to focus on the problem.  It should help **you** focus as well.  [Don Kirkby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58573884/901925) got it right.

Let's try that `arange` by itself:

```
In [7]: np.arange(0, time, 0.001)                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b37c7a8fd737> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange(0, time, 0.001)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`arange` expects a `stop`, `start` and `step`.  All should be scalars, not arrays.  The error indicates that at some point it is testing size the `stop` value, either that it's bigger than the `start` or relative to some intermediate value.  If you do `

A comparison on an array produces a boolean array:

```
In [9]: 2 <= np.arange(3)                                                       
Out[9]: array([False, False,  True])
```

Such an array cannot be used in Python context that expects a scalar boolean, such as a `if` or `and`.  That's the kind of situation that produces this `ambiguity` error.  Here it occurs inside the compiled `arange` function, so is a little harder to diagnose.  In any case, the problem lies in using an array as argument to `arange`.  I'm not going to guess as to why you are using two `arange`, one outside `phi` and one inside it.  You need to sort that out for yourself.